# How to check if a function exist (but not inherited) in python?

Tags: python

Kind of related to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708525/how-to-check-if-mako-function-exist

I want to check if a function exists for a given class, but not inherited, so that the parent can called the child's function, since otherwise it would result in an infinite recursion..

edit:

it actually gives a maximum stack level error, which is the same.

the equivalent code would be:

```
class A(object):
    def f(x):
        b = B()
        b.f()

class B(A):
    pass

a = A()
a.f()
```

i understand this is not clean or preferred, but it is what the template translates to, and I dunno how to check for it otherwise.

Comment: The child's function will automatically be called, so I don't see the point of this.

Comment: Infinite recursion? I don't think that's possible. Can you show an example of what you mean by that?

Comment: Adding an example doesn't make this question any better.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want to check if a function exists for a given class, but not inherited

Yes, you can check the class dictionary directly.  Either use the *__dict__* attribute or the built-in *[vars()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars)* function::

```
>>> class A(object):
        def f(x):
            pass

>>> class B(A):
        def g(x):
            pass

>>> 'f' in vars(B)
False
>>> 'g' in vars(B)
True
```

Comment: but `f in vars(A)` will be `True` even when `f` is non-function variable. one should use `type` to check if it's function or not.

Comment: @p.kolya You seem to be reading more into the question than was actually posed ;-)  Also, your proposed amendment is too restrictive, ``type(f) == type(lambda :0)`` won't work for some kinds of callables.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is to check whether the method is defined directly in instance's class and not in one of its ancestors then you can try this:

```
import inspect

def has_method(obj, name):
    v = vars(obj.__class__)
    # check if name is defined in obj's class and that name is a method
    return name in v and inspect.isroutine(v[name])

class A:
    def foo(self):
        print 'foo'

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
a = A()

print has_method(a, 'foo') # => True
print has_method(b, 'foo') # => False
```